# C- program : Memory overflow for hash table using array of linked lists

Tags: c, linked-list, hashtable

System has 16GB RAM. Our node structure for storing in the linked list of the hash table has a size of 38bytes. This tells that we can store up to 452million nodes in the hash table. But only after 13million nodes(approx.) the memory overflow takes place.

The relevant code segment is this:

```
for (i=0;i<NO_OF_BUCKETS;i++)
  {  
    nextptr = hashtable[i];
    while (nextptr != NULL)
      {
        prevptr = nextptr;
        nextptr = nextptr->next;
        free(prevptr);
      }
    hashtable[i] = NULL;
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by `nextptr = nextptr->next;`?? There is no `next` to `nextptr`. There is only `NULL`. It should be `prevptr->next = nextptr;` `prevptr = prevptr->next;` and NO `free(prevptr)` else you will loose the pointer.

Comment: What do you mean "memory overflow"?

Comment: @noMAD No, assuming `nextptr` points to a structure containing a `next` member which is a pointer to the same type, the code is fine. The naming is suboptimal.

Comment: Your code seems fine - but it doesn't seem to have anything to do with what you're talking about.  It looks like cleanup code to deallocate nodes in the hash table.  What does that have to do with your problem?  And what exactly *is* your problem?  Are you running out of memory?  What *error* are you getting?

Comment: So your code frees all items in the hash table. Doesn't sound like that could cause an out of memory error, at least after already having freed some. Maybe it's crashing because you have a loop in the linked list or some other structure problem?

Comment: are you building your application 64bit? I don't know what other memory requirements your application with the huge list has, but you are at ~ 1/2 GB with just the 13M item list (if your 38 bytes value is accurate) could you be hitting a 2 GB memory boundary?

Comment: Why the downvotes ? this is a very valid question

Answer (score 1):

```
System has 16GB RAM. Our node structure for storing in the linked list of the hash table has a size of 38bytes. This tells that we can store up to 452million nodes in the hash table.
```

Now that's a wrong assumption. Do you think all of the RAM will be reserved for the data in your application? Not at all. There are the operating system, other userland applications, etc. which also require memory, and you can't even exactly tell how much they need. So don't expect that you can calculate the number of elements in your linked list implementation.

Comment: Yes but 38 bytes * 452 M list elements is no more than about 500 MB.

Comment: NOPEEEEEE... 38 * 452 000 000 = 17 176 000 000 (3 000 000 bytes less than 16 GB), grab a calculator if you don't believe me...